# Image processing - Character count in dot printed text

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, matlab-cvst

I have to count the characters that is printed in a beverage tin[1]. So far i have done till removing noise and unwanted pixels and now my text is clear to read [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w63wd.png)  but is there any way to count them properly. Ocr fails to detect this text. Or should i join these dots using some algorithm and continue with ocr function?

[ROI of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w63wd.png)

Here is the code which gave me the above picture.

```
clear all; close all;
a=imread('coke.jpg');
gray=rgb2gray(a);
thres=150;
lbw=double(gray>thres);
imwrite(lbw,'--\OCR\output.png');

a=imread('output.png');
c=imresize(a,.5);
b = im2bw(c, .9);
b=imcomplement(b);
imwrite(b,'compli.png');
```

Comment: I think OCR is failing because of the edges around the tin, not that it cannot read the text, you want to cut out the 4 corners around the tin.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Nope. I have removed everything and converted into a binary image with only the text in white and everything else is black. ROI is only the text.

Comment: Show the code that does this. Your question will be closed because you haven't showed us what you've tried or where you're stuck.

Comment: @GameOfThrows and there is no need of recognising characters, counting them is suffecient.

Comment: @rayryeng i havent done much with the code yet and i have posted the picture in ROI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely join the dots. The first thing I would try is the `imclose` function, which does morphological closing (dilation followed by erosion).

For example, you could try this:

```
im = imread('dotMatrix.png');
im2 = imclose(im, strel('line', 5, 90));
im3 = imclose(im2, strel('line', 5, 45));
```

[image]